# PHP running out of memory in all my scripts

Tags: apache, memory, php

EDIT:

My php.ini has 256MB memory set:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 250     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 120    ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 256MB    ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (256MB)
```

So I had a certain PHP script which was not very well written and when I executed it the PHP ran out of memory and my PC froze. Before running the script I have increased the memory limit in php.ini. I have changed it back to the default value after.

Now the problem is it seems to have done something to my PHP installation. Every PHP script I execute now is telling me it has not enough memmory. The scripts that have worked before without an issue.

It seems like the one bad script I mentioned earlier is still running in the background somehow.

I have restarted PHP, Apache, I have restarted my PC and even went to sleep for 8 hours. The next thing in the morning I find out all PHP scripts are still running out of memory. What the hell?

I am getting errors like this everywhere now (with the file in the error changing of course) - with every single even the simplest PHP script:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6144 bytes) in D:\data\o\WebLib\src\Db\Db.php on line 241
>
> Fatal error (shutdown): Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6144 bytes) in D:\data\o\WebLib\src\Db\Db.php on line 241

Ok here is the script (I have commented out the bad parts):

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(BASE_PATH.'/../WebLib/config/paths.php');             

require_once(PATH_TO_LIB3D_SRC.'/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once(PATH_TO_LIB3D_SRC.'/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/IReadFilter.php');

///**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */ 
//class chunkReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {     
//  private $_startRow = 0;     
//  private $_endRow = 0;     
//  /**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */ 
//    public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) 
//    { 
//        $this->_startRow    = $startRow; 
//        $this->_endRow      = $startRow + $chunkSize;     
//    } 
//    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') 
//    {         
//      //  Only read the heading row, and the rows that are configured in $this->_startRow and $this->_endRow 
//        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) { 
//            return true;         
//        }         
//        return false;     
//    } 
//} 
//
//function ReadXlsxTableIntoArray($theFilePath)
//{ 
//  $arrayData                  = 
//  $arrayOriginalColumnNames   = 
//  $arrayColumnNames           = array();
//  
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
//  /**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
//  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
//  /**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/ 
//  $chunkSize = 10; 
//  /**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/ 
//  $chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter(); 
//  /**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter that we've Instantiated  **/ 
//  $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
//  $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
//  /**  Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks  **/ 
//  /**  $startRow is set to 2 initially because we always read the headings in row #1  **/
//  for ($startRow = 1; $startRow <= 65536; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
//      /**  Tell the Read Filter, the limits on which rows we want to read this iteration  **/ 
//      $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize); 
//      /**  Load only the rows that match our filter from $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/ 
//      $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($theFilePath); 
//      //    Do some processing here
//      
//      $rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
//      foreach($rowIterator as $row){
//          
//          $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
//          //$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
//          if(1 == $row->getRowIndex ()) {
//              foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
//                  $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
//                  $arrayOriginalColumnNames[] = $value;
//                  // let's remove the diacritique
//                  $value = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $value);
//                  // and white spaces
//                  $valueExploded = explode(' ', $value);
//                  $value = '';
//                  // capitalize the first letter of each word
//                  foreach ($valueExploded as $word) {
//                      $value .= ucfirst($word);
//                  }
//                  $arrayColumnNames[] = $value;
//              }
//              continue;
//          } else {
//              $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
//              reset($arrayColumnNames);
//              foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
//                  $arrayData[$rowIndex][current($arrayColumnNames)] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
//                  next($arrayColumnNames);
//              }
//          }
//          
//          unset($cellIterator);
//      }
//      
//      unset($rowIterator);
//  }
//  
//  // Free up some of the memory 
//  $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets(); 
//  unset($objPHPExcel); 
//  
//  return array($arrayOriginalColumnNames, $arrayColumnNames, $arrayData);
//}
//
//if (isset($_POST['uploadFile'])) {
//  //list($tableOriginalColumnNames, $tableColumnNames, $tableData) = ReadXlsxTableIntoArray($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']);
//  //CreateXMLSchema($tableOriginalColumnNames, 'schema.xml');
//  //echo GetReplaceDatabaseTableSQL('posta_prehlad_hp', $tableColumnNames, $tableData);
//}
```

Comment: can't you increase the allowed memory size in php.ini

Comment: It seems pretty clear that your memory settings are not correct. Try using "256M" and not "256MB" in your configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the php.ini :

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Note that you're not supposed to use **MB** or **KB**, but **M** or **K**

Answer (score 4):

PHP expects the unit Megabyte to be denoted by the single letter **M**. You've specified *256MB*. Notice the extra *B*.

Since PHP doesn't understand the unit *MB*, it falls back to the lowest known "named" unit: kilobyte (**K**).

Simply remove the extra *B* from your setting and it should properly read the value as 256 megabyte (**256M**)

Please see the following FAQ entry on data size units:

> [PHP: Using PHP - Manual](http://www.php.net/using#faq.using.shorthandbytes)

Answer (score 3):

You have a [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits) of `256K`. Thats much to less in nearly all cases. The default value is `16M` (since 5.2).

Comment: I have 256MB memory set in php.ini so that seems weird. I don't understand. Check my post I have added excerpt of my php.ini.

Comment: You should read the manual, its `256M` in `php.ini`, not `256MB`. Its clearly mentioned in your error message. There is the number `262144 bytes` which is not 256MB.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you set your memory size back correctly? The error shows that your max memory is `262144 bytes`, and that is a quarter of an MB. That's really low!

As reaction to your php settings: shouldn't that syntax be

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

I don't know if it accepts both M and MB, but it might not?

Comment: I have 256MB memory set in php.ini so that seems weird. I don't understand. Check my post I have added excerpt of my php.ini.

Comment: @Richard: Even if you copy&paste your one comment to every answer, it stays wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hey Richard. The changes couldn't have been executed since PHP clearly states that you only have `256K` set as limit. Look through the php.ini and all the other places. It could be located in a .htaccess file on the vhost/host.

Comment: I have 256MB memory set in php.ini so that seems weird. I don't understand. Check my post I have added excerpt of my php.ini.

Comment: Hey @Richard Knop, have you tried adding this line to your script? ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); 

Or perhaps the previous answers solved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted Apache after you edited php.ini and increased the `memory_limit = 256MB`?